# Can infinite integral domain be a field

Tags: integral-domain

Every finite integral domain is field. I was wondering can some infinite integral domain be field?

Comment: Any infinite field is also an infinite integral domain

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $\mathbb{Q}$ is an infinite integral domain which is also a field (of course, *any* infinite field is also an infinite integral domain). What you may want to say is that not every infinite integral domain needs to be a field. Here $\mathbb{Z}$ is a good example, or more generally $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ for $d\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Related: [Every integral domain with finitely many ideals is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428221/show-that-an-integral-domain-with-finitely-many-ideals-is-a-field?rq=1).

Comment: Every integral domain, including infinite ones, can be extended to an overring that is a field using localization.  This construction is often called the [quotient field or field of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions).  The integral domain $\mathbb{Z}$ has as its quotient field $\mathbb{Q}$.