# How to directly prove every element in a ring with exactly three ideals is either a unit or a zero divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

It is known that [every element in a ring with finitely many ideals is either a unit or a zero divisor.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901876/every-element-in-a-ring-with-finitely-many-ideals-is-either-a-unit-or-a-zero-div)

Now consider a ring $R$ with exactly three ideals. Take an element $x$ such that $(x)\neq (1)$. For $y\in R$ and $y\notin (x)$, there are two possible cases:

1. $(y)=(1)$
2. $(y)\neq(1)$. Then $(y)=(x)$, that is $x=ys=xts$ for some $s,t\in R$. It follows that $$x(1-ts)=0$$
   which implies that $x$ is a zero divisor.

However, if there is no such a $y$ of the second case, how to prove $x$ is a zero divisor?

Comment: Actually, this question can be interpreted as "is there a ring $R$ with three exactly ideals $\{0\},~\{0,x\}$ and $R$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either $(x^2)=(x)$ or $(x^2)=\{0\}$. The former case is impossible, because, by Nakayama's lemma, $(x)$ is generated by an idempotent $e$, but then in that case there would be at least four ideals, $\{0\}$, $eR$ $(1-e)R$ and $R$ among them.

(Alternatively you can just work out the consequences of $x^2r=x$ assuming $x$ isn't a zero divisor or unit.)

So you only have the first case, where $x^2=0$.

> is there a ring $R$ with three exactly ideals $\{0\}$, $\{0,x\}$,  and $R$

Yes, of course: $F_2[x]/(x^2)$.

Actually, for any commutative ring and nonidempotent maximal ideal $M\lhd R$, $R/M^2$ has exactly three ideals, but you went further and specified that the maximal ideal only has two elements...

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know why someone gave the downvote. I gave an upvote, and this answer is really great. I learned a lot from this answer. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped! @AolongLi

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with only one nonzero proper ideal, $I$ say.

Let $x \in I$, where $x \ne 0$. Since $I$ is a proper ideal, $x$ is not a unit.

Then $(x)$ is a nonzero proper ideal of $R$, hence we must have $I=(x)$.

Suppose $x$ is not a zero divisor.

Then $x^2 \ne 0$, and $(x^2) \subseteq (x)$, so $(x^2)$ is a nonzero proper ideal of $R$.

Hence we must have $I = (x^2)$, and thus, $(x^2) = (x)$.

Then $x = rx^2$ for some $r \in R$, so $x(rx-1)=0$.

But $x$ is not a zero divisor, hence we must have $rx = 1$, contradiction, since $x$ is not a unit.

Thus, $x$ must be a zero divisor.

Hence, noting that $0$ is also a zero divisor, all elements of $I$ are zero divisors.

Next suppose $y \in R,\;y \notin I$.

Then $y \ne 0$, so $(y)$ is a nonzero ideal with $(y) \ne I$.

It follows that $(y)=(1)$, hence $y$ is a unit.

Thus we've shown that all elements of $I$ are zero divisors, and all elements of $R\setminus I$ are units.

Comment: Could I just say let $x\ne 0$; then if $(x)=(1)$, we are done. If not, $(x)=I$. Suppose $x$ isn't a zero divisor, we must prove it's a unit. Then apply your argument: $(x^2)\ne(0)$. If $(x^2)=(1)$, we are done. Otherwise $(x^2)=(x)$ and $x=rx^2\iff x(rx-1)=0\implies rx=1$, so $x$ is a unit.

Comment: @user437309: Yes, that's the essence of my argument.

Comment: So there is no need to consider the cases $x\in I$ and $y\notin I$ separately, right?

Comment: @user437309: Effectively, you're doing that.

Comment: Yes, my original question was whether I can consider only one case, and I gave a modification of your proof in which I consider only one case. Now I see I can.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no such a $y$ of the second case, we have to look at $(x)$.

If there exists $z\in (x)$ and $z\neq x$, then we have $(z)=(x)$. Thus, $x=zs=xts$ for some $s,t\in R$. It follows that $x(1−ts)=0$. So $x$ is a zero divisor.

If there is no other element besides $x$, that is, the ring has three ideals：
  $$\{0\},~\{0,x\},~ R$$
If there exists $y\neq x$ and $y\in R$, then $y=1$. Otherwise $\{0,x\}$ is not a ideal. And $x^2=0$, which implies that $x$ is a zero divisor.